# Why am I getting "isupper is not defined" error?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

learning python and working with some basic string methods.

I have this program which finds the index of the first lowercase char in a string:

```
def find_lower(word):
i = 0
while not isupper(word[i]):
    i = i+1
return i
```

however, when I run this code, I get the error

```
builtins.NameError: name 'isupper' is not defined
```

Do I need to import a module or something for `isupper()` to work?

Comment: is upper is a method of string. It must be called on a string like `word[i].isupper()`.

Comment: Instead of racing to answer and aiming for reps, OP should be directed to the documentation page for his sake. This problem can be found on web with just a few clicks, they should be encouraged for research and exploration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `isupper` incorrectly. It is not a built in standalone function. It is a method of `str`. The documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper).

For any function that you are unsure of you can consult the python documentation. It is well indexed by google so a google search is a good place to begin when you want to understand how to use a function.

Once that is out of the way, your `find_lower` has a few more issues. It actually finds the index of the first upper case letter due to a logic error.

```
while not word[i].isupper():
```

Continues to loop if the character is not upper case and stops if it is. So you need to remove the `not`.

```
def find_lower(word):
    i = 0
    while word[i].isupper():
        i = i+1
    return i

print(find_lower('ABcDE')) # prints 2
```

The next error is that if there are no lowercase characters it walks off the end of the string and throws an exception

```
>print(find_lower('ABCDE'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myisupper.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(find_lower('ABCDE'))
  File "./myisupper.py", line 5, in find_lower
    while word[i].isupper():
IndexError: string index out of range
```

To fix this you need to limit the number of iterations to the length of the string, this is left as an exercise to fix.

Comment: Great! Caught errors that others failed to find out.

Comment: Well the question was just about `str.upper`, so its not really fair to compare. I always test out answers and saw those issues, so thought I'd mention them.

Comment: no probs, feel free to accept the answer that you found most useful.

Answer (score 3):

isupper is a method of string. so, you should use it on a string

For example,

```
a = "Hello"

#You can check upper on this as follows
print(a.isupper())
```

In your case, change the following

```
while not isupper(word[i]):
```

to

```
while not word[i].isupper():
    print("Your x here")
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! How do I know when I am supposed to use a method *on* something vs putting something in the parens (like for print(x) for example).

Comment: @mc-lunar The updated answer does not contain any information regarding to your question. If you want to find answer to your question, you need to understand the difference between a method and a function. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/155609/4237254

Answer (score 2):

`isupper` is a method of string, and should be called by that object: `word[i].isupper()`.

Comment: Thank you. How do I know when something is supposed to go before the method and when something is supposed to go in parens (eg : print(i) )

Answer (score 1):

it should be like

```
def find_lower(word):
  i = 0
  while not word[i].isupper():
      i = i+1
  return i
```